# How do I resize a text box by dragging with mouse?

Tags: asp.net

I am using web application.I have used C#,SQL,ASP.NET.I want resize textbox by dragging it so user can enter text.How to do that?.I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: You can use TextArea instead of textbox

Comment: Yes I can use textarea ,but I want it as resizeable by dragging with mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jqueryUI Resizable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Comment: Thanks Ehssan,thanks for ur help.I visited that page.Inside code,they used js : //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: can't you use the jquery library ?!

Comment: Does it is necessary to use that library?Without it jquery will work?How good to use that library in ur project?Is it safe.I never used jquery before it.I usually used javascript.

Comment: Jquery is a mature library. It is very popular and in web development is a must in these days... There are many tutorials for it. Try it. It will change your development life :)